# Recover redirected folder

Tags: bash

I have redirected my `/var/cache/apt` folder to `/media/anotherdisk/DATA/apt`, so that apt file looks like this now: `apt -> /media/anotherdisk/DATA/apt`. I would like to undo this, but not sure how to do it. Sorry for the naive question, thanks in advance.

Comment: Please share contents of `/etc/fstab`, or check it for *`anotherdisk`* occurency.

Comment: Here I paste from 8th line on:
UUID=ae0d94cc-50ad-43cf-b30e-b5d1f9d9e906 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot/efi was on /dev/nvme0n1p1 during installation
UUID=D684-F7B2  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0       1
# /home was on /dev/nvme0n1p7 during installation
UUID=4514de6b-68d8-4e00-abb4-e32cfd0bfb4e /home           ext4    defaults        0       2
# swap was on /dev/nvme0n1p5 during installation
UUID=c262e4dc-aa20-4d82-bad7-1da3ed7a5f1d none            swap    sw              0       0

Comment: Then `mount | grep anotherdisk`; `ls -al /var/cache/apt`

Comment: /dev/sda1 on /media/anotherdisk/DATA type fuseblk (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,default_permissions,allow_other,blksize=4096,uhelper=udisks2)
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 23 Nov 14  2019 /var/cache/apt -> /media/anotherdisk/DATA/apt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Managed to do it simply by deleting the symlink and moving apt folder back to `/var/cache`. I initially couldn't do this due to permission issues, but it worked as sudo.